# How to allow a remote user to connect over ssh on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ssh, user-management, sshd, adduser

Before you yell me out, I already checked the answers on the web but couldn't install the system that I want correctly. Here is what I want:

- Allow a remote user to connect (to my pc) over `ssh` and able to use all the installed components like `python, g++, opencv`, etc.
- Restrict the user in his own assigned subfolder like `/home/remoteuser`
- I want the user to able to see correct prompt after login, like: `user@host:$` (not `-bash-4.4$`)
- I want the user to use all the bash commands since the solutions I have found so far don't allow the user to use even `ls`.

And I believe all the Linux users need all in one answer.

Last: I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

**EDIT:**

- I have tried the way explained here: https://sxi.io/debian-ubuntu-linux-restrict-an-ssh-user-session-to-a-specific-directory-by-setting-chrooted-jail.html
- Also, I have changed some options in `sshd_config`, like:

`#ClientAliveInterval 0` to `ClientAliveInterval 300`

`#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` to `PermitRootLogin yes`

`#PubkeyAuthentication blabla` to `PubkeyAuthentication yes`

`#Subsystem sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` to `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`

Added this block also:

```
##Apply the chrooted jail to the user called tom and jerry
Match User myremoteuser
ChrootDirectory /home/myremoteuser
## Allow sftp to chrooted jail ##
#ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowUsers myremoteuser
```

Comment: Enable `sshd` & create a user with the restricted access you want.  They need read access outside their own directory, otherwise they won't be able to run any commands (the need to see into the directory where commands are located, and then execute things there for commands to work).  $PS1 is fully configurable.  User to create is "remoteuser" in your example.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried and the outcome. For restricting the user, look at restricted shell, like `rbash`.

Comment: @SorenA actually I tried here: https://sxi.io/debian-ubuntu-linux-restrict-an-ssh-user-session-to-a-specific-directory-by-setting-chrooted-jail.html

Comment: @guiverc I tried here: https://sxi.io/debian-ubuntu-linux-restrict-an-ssh-user-session-to-a-specific-directory-by-setting-chrooted-jail.html but I am open to any other easy way or a link that describes it.

Comment: @WhoCares .. for chroot jails, you need to have all commands copied into the chroot environment, as is described in the page you refers to, little over halfway down with `ls` as an example. If you need all commands, the rbash I mentioned earlier might be an easier solution.

Comment: @SorenA thanks, I am open `rbash` too but please tell me, do I have to remove all the things I have done so far?